# Have a serious issue in my blog app, done all authentication but, when i create a post the user_id is not passing. Please help me

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I just done all authentication process, but when i create a post user_id is not passing so user name is not seen in the post. The code in the **PostController**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @user = User.all

end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
    @cat = Categorie.all
    @us = User.all
end

def create
    params.permit!
    @catt = @cat_id
    @post = Post.new(post_params) 



    # @cat = @post.categorie_id

     if (@post).save
         redirect_to(:action => 'index')
     else
         render('new')
     end
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)

        redirect_to @post

        else

         render('edit')
    end

end

def delete
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to(:action => "index")
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :categorie_id, @us_id)
end
end
```

In the **PostController, Index action** I have this code

```
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <%= link_to(:action => 'show', :id => post) do %>



       <b>Post by -- <%= post.user.first_name %> --</b> 

       <i>"<%= post.title %>"</i>

    <% end %> <%= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %>

       <p class = ""><%= post.body %></p> <hr/>

<% end %>
```

I have this in my form. THe form doesn't contain any user related thing

```
<%= f.collection_select :categorie_id, Categorie.all, :id, :title, :prompt => 'Select One' %>
```

The User.id is not saving, so the user name is not visible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate the records. When using devise for authentication you have a current_user object (if the user is signed in) so you can change your create method from:

```
def create
params.permit!
@catt = @cat_id
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

to

```
def create
params.permit!
@catt = @cat_id
@post = Post.new(post_params) 
@post.user_id = current_user.id
```

For this to work the posts table needs to have a user_id field (integer) and the models need a has_many :posts (in the user model) and belongs_to :user (in the post model).

Then you can call the user name in your views like post.user.first_name

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, It works, Actually I did't use devise, I am using it manually, I am just learning it. But it works with your clue current_user object. That's I use session[:first_name]. Thanks Nikolai :)